# jQuery Slider with focus control

Tags: jquery, slider, focus, setinterval

Does anyone knows a slider plugin that has focus control? I mean, when the user clicks on a link and goes into another page, when the user comes back, the slider will start all over again from image 1. I need it to pause whenever the plugin loses focus and then resume on the way back.

In the end i think it's not just focus control. It has to save/remember the position when the user leaves into another page... I'm converting the HTML in phonegap to android and ios.

I'm using https://github.com/daledavies/jQuery-Easy-Slides , but can't seem to find an option for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try Owl Carousel. It has many control options.

http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#more-demos

Comment: Unfortunately it does not have the feature